# Custom zsh completion: custom sort?

Tags: zsh, zsh-completion

I'm using `_values` to add completion to a custom zsh command, but unfortunately, zsh ignores the order in which I pass the values and sorts in reverse order of what I what (I want `sort -rn`, basically).

Is there anyway to force it to respect the order I've passed, or if not, to somehow modify the sorting mechanism used *for that specific command* (i.e., I don't want to change the order of *all* completions, just this specific one.

Example:

```
_values 'my completions' foo bar
```

shows `bar` before `foo`, but I want `foo` before `bar`.

Comment: Are you referring to glob expansions?

Comment: Not, I'm referring to tab completions. The list passed to the `_values` function is created without globs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, Zsh completion matches can be added in either a sorted or unsorted group. However, `_values` does not include an option to specify this. So you can do:

```
_wanted -V values expl 'my completions' compadd foo bar
```

Which features of `_values` do you want? If you want a delimited list with no duplicates, `_sequence` can wrap the above. If you want per-match descriptions, `_describe` can help. But if you want some of the more complex features of `_values`, you're either stuck with the sorting or you have to do a lot more manually.

Comment: I've tried using `_describe`, but when I added the `-V` option to it, it doesn't seem to work. My code is [here](https://pastebin.com/dcaHYpga). When I try to complete `hello`, it isn't ordered but the description of the match group is changed to `-V`. If I replace the 'stuff' string with, say, 'my desc', it only completes the first entry in the array, and it includes the description as part of the completion, i.e., `hello foo:foo\ desc`, which is all sorts of odd.

Comment: Your code works for me in zsh 5.4.2 (and also 5.2) but not in 5.0.2. Perhaps try a newer zsh release?

Comment: Unfortunately, my work station is limited to 5.0.5 :( Thanks for verifying the root cause though!

Comment: I stumbled over this question while researching why my `git checkout` recent branches completion was sorted the wrong way (lexical instead of MRO). They use `_describe -V` internally. The fix was to turn off `list-grouped` for the tag[1]. I guess the grouping will mess up the order (sorta makes sense).

[1] `zstyle ':completion:*:*:git-checkout:*:recent-branches' list-grouped false`